# Microsoft Edge does not render the Pdf stream

Tags: c#, pdf, microsoft-edge

I have the following application returning a PDF document as a FileStreamResult. Microsoft Edge is not rendering the PDF document. Anyone know how to fix this? or This is a known issue of Microsoft Edge?

```
public FileStreamResult Get()
{
    MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream).CloseStream = false;

    document.Open();
    document.Add( new Paragraph("Hello World") );
    document.Add( new Paragraph( DateTime.Now.ToString() ) );
    document.Close();

    byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
    workStream.Write( byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length );
    workStream.Position = 0;

    return new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

Thanks
Niranjan

Comment: may be help http://forums.asp.net/t/1549431.aspx?Code+to+render+the+report+in+PDF+format+using+C+in+SSRS+2008

Comment: Thank you Nalaka, But this issue is specific to Edge only. It works in all other browsers. Since Edge only uses Windows.Data.Pdf.dll instead of adobe plug in to render, not too sure whether this is a bug with Edge.

Comment: What is Edge doing? Is there an error? a broken render?

Comment: I got it fixed after updating the windows.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed after updating the Windows 10 new updates. Thanks a lot for the responses.